# Не работает метод strprime

Tags: python, datetime

Я использую datetime, но не работает метод strptime. Помогите, если сможете.

```
from datetime import date, datetime   
def get_events():
    list_events = []
    with open('events.txt', encoding='ansi') as file:
        for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        current_event = line.split(',')
        event_date = datetime.strptime(current_event[1], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
        current_event[1] = event_date
    list_events.append(current_event)
    return list_events
```

Вызываю эту функцию и выскакивает эта ошибка:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module '_strptime' has no attribute '_strptime_datetime' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: у тебя там в папке проекта не лежит случайно файл datetime.py ?

Comment: Нет, не лежит..

Comment: а что есть? там чтото с конфликтующем с питоном именем

Comment: Попробуйте отдельно протестировать метод strptime в модуле datetime. print(datetime.strptime("2015-4-4", "%Y-%m-%d").date()). Если выражение будет работать, перепишите свой код с проверкой переменной current_event[1]